# Newbie: where do i upload Apache modules to?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

Forgive such a naive question but I am a web designer performing some maintenance tasks for a new client.

I'm relatively new to Apache configuration and the Linux command line.

I'd like to install the [Google Pagespeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/) on a development server.

Server = Debian 64bit with Apache 2.4

I have downloaded the package to my PC, and I understand from [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download) I eventually need to run the commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but I believe before I do this, I need to upload the package (`mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb`) to the remote host.

My question is: where do I upload it to (over SFTP)? I have root access on SFTP.

I've Googled `where to upload apache module to` without getting an answer, and the Google Pagespeed documentation probably assumes a better understanding of Apache than I have.

Answer (score 5):

OK, first let me clear something up: `mod-pagespeed-*.deb` is not an apache module. It's a debian-style software package. It's analogous to an `exe` or `msi` in Windows world or a `pkg` in OSX world.

It does not really matter where you upload the package. You'll be installing the package after uploading it, and the installer will take care of putting all of its files in the correct place.

I typically maintain a `~/downloads/` folder that I use for things like this.

---

As an aside:

> I have root access on SFTP.

Please. Don't do that. Remote root login, via ssh/sftp/etc should be disabled. Additionally, get key authentication set up and disable password authentication. These actions are the **bare minimum** steps you must do to secure your server.

---

As a second aside:

> Forgive such a naive question but I am a web designer performing some
>   maintenance tasks for a new client.

Does your client know that they have an absolute sysadmin novice poking around in their server? Please, don't take offense at this - I'm sure you're a very capable web dev. Sysadmin isn't your thing. *That's OK*. I'd **highly** suggest that you enlist the help of a seasoned linux admin for this sort of thing. You'd be amazed what could be accomplished in the span of an hour or two with a professional.

Comment: OK. I mean I can access the folder root. I don't login as root.